# Convert MySQL database to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using this code below to convert database to JSON.

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json');

mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die('cannot connect');
mysql_select_db('sanpham');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cpu";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result)
{
    echo 'Lỗi SQL: '.mysql_error();
    echo "\r\n<br />";
    echo 'SQL: '.$sql;
    exit;
}
$rows = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $rows[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);


?>
```

In my PHP file no error, no database, nothing display.

Comment: add this at the top of your page : `ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: What is the error log telling you?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile <br />
  <b>Deprecated</b>:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\server\data\data-cpu.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
it tell me use mysqli

Comment: @mayersdesign no error log . nothing display TT

Comment: thats good here is a good place to start : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Deprecated : mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in**

As the warning suggest use either pdo or mysqli.

**mysqli :**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "sanpham";

// Create connection
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cpu";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($rows);
} else {
    echo "no results found";
}
```

**PDO :**

```
<?php

$host    = 'localhost';
$db      = 'sanpham';
$user    = 'root';
$pass    = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM cpu");
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: ok thank you ! but i think should use echo json_encode in while loop to display all result in database .

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the json_encode method on an array storing the data of your mysql database ex:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$db = "psychocodes";
$user = "your username";  //enter your database username
$pass = "your password";  //enter your database password
$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db); 
$rows = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die("cannot write");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo "<pre>";
print json_encode(array('serverres'=>$rows));
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Reference : [How to Convert MySQL database table into JSON using PHP](http://www.psychocodes.in/how-to-convert-mysql-database-table-into-json-using-php.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use this,

```
<?php
    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","dbname") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select * from tablename";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: You have a mistake in your code. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)